# Implementing Naive Bayes Classifier with naivebayes and Caret in R

Tags: r, r-caret, naivebayes

I have an existing predictive model using naivebayes package. What I'm currently trying to do is replicate my model using Caret. The reason for this is because I'd like to run ***varImp()*** function to see the list of significant variables from Caret. I have managed to run Naive Bayes Classifier using Caret, but the problem is that when I do the prediction to make sure the model from using Caret aligns with the model from using naivebayes, I end up with different results. Could someone please advice how I can replicate my existing Naive Bayes Classifier using Caret?

```
# Naive Bayes Classifier using naivebayes
nb = naive_bayes(y ~ ., data = df, usekernel = T)

# Naive Bayes Classifier using Caret
Grid = data.frame(usekernel = TRUE, laplace = 0, adjust = 1)
caret = train(y ~ ., data = df,
              method = 'naive_bayes',
              na.action = na.pass,
              trControl = trainControl(method = "none"),
              tuneGrid = Grid)
```

Much appreciated in advance.

Thanks!

Comment: you can get different results even you run same model. maybe defining set.seed() can help you.

Comment: Hi @patula, thanks for the reply. There are a few things that are being neglected from my code above, but yeah I have defined set.seed() so the training data is the same for the both approach.

Comment: Hi Brian, I substituted the `iris` dataset for `df` and `Species` for `y`. I then run your code and predicted the iris dataset  using nb and caret objects - I got exactly the same probabilities. You maybe use different test data. Cannot tell anything more without additional informations.